# Unable to update label prior to function call

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to update a simple label control prior to calling a function in another class but the label only updates after the function call completes.  The code is below.

```
lblCalling.Text = "Calling...";
bool res = pf_auth.pf_authenticate(pfAuthParams, out otp, out callStatus, out errorId);
```

Comment: Dear Adoyt are you using Web forms? If so, I can only assume that the code you running is on the server. As such the label will not be update until the code on the serve finished running. Remember the client (ie web browse) and the server are not linked and run independently of one another.

Answer (score 0):

NO, I don't think so. Rather, in your code the label gets updated as it supposed to but most probably the following method takes long time and you are running in STA (single threaded) mode and so your main UI thread is block; not allowing you to see the update probably.

Run the method `pf_auth.pf_authenticate()` in separate thread probably

Comment: Tried to do that using the example above but didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public await void DoWork()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        lblCalling.Text = "Calling...";
    });
    bool res = pf_auth.pf_authenticate(pfAuthParams, out otp, out callStatus, out errorId);
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer, give it a try. What version of Visual Studio do you have?